# Angular only uses prod environment, how do I fix that

Tags: angular

As I am getting ready to deploy the Angular front-end I have set-up the environments to access API at different URLs. This was easy, but it seems that my Angular uses prod environment variables even on dev server.

environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
   production: false,
   api: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'
};
```

Import used in every component:

```
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't upgrade your angular version properly when going to v12. To run the appropriate migrations do:

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from 11 --to 12
```

After that make sure that your `angular.json` has the following property at `projects.{PROJECT_NAME}.architect.build.defaultConfiguration`:

```
"defaultConfiguration": "development"
```

---

and with your next upgrade, make sure to use the `ng update @angular/cli` command :)

Comment: I didn't upgrade from 11 to 12, this project used 12 from the start, but the defaultConfiguration for build was set at production for some reason, thank you for your help

Comment: @PurryFury oh that's weird :D oh well, glad that i pointed you in the right direction